# How to compile fortran code to run without gfortran installed

Tags: macos, static, compilation, makefile, fortran

I have downloaded Bellhop, which is an underwater acoustic simulator written in Fortran. It can be found [here](http://oalib.hlsresearch.com/Modes/AcousticsToolbox/at.zip) with the Makefile.

**Question 1: I would like to know if it is possible to compile Fortran code, including everything needed, so a user without gfortran installed, can run it.**

I have read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranGettingStarted) the following:

> **static linking**
>   *This section does not apply to Windows users, except for Cygwin users with gcc4-4.3.2-2 or later.*
>   gfortran is composed of two main parts: the compiler, which creates the executable program from your code, and the library, which is used when you run your program afterwards. That explains why, if gfortran is installed in a non-standard directory, it may compile your code fine but the executable may fail with an error message like library not found. One way to avoid this (more ideas can be found on the binaries page) is to use the so-called "static linking", available with option **-static gfortran then put the library code inside the program created, thus enabling it to run without the library present** **(like, on a computer where gfortran is not installed**). Complete example is:

```
gfortran -static myfile.f -o program.exe
```

Reading this, I suppose that it is possible to do what I'm asking but I'm not very familiarized with fortran and makefiles. I don't understand this:

> put the library code inside the program created

**Question 2: How can I put the library code inside the program? Where can I find the library? What does "inside the program" means?**

I'm running OSX 10.9.4 and gfortran

Comment: Static linkage of libgfortran is what you need to do. Fully static binary is easiest way to be sure you've got it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem about compiling Fortran code with gfortran using static libraries.
As @M.S.B. said, using `static-libgfortran` worked for me under MacOS.

If somebody is having issues with linking the libquadmath.0.dylb library, remove **libquadmath.0.dylib** and **libquadmath.dylib** from /usr/local/gfortran/lib/

This doest the trick. Further information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590525/correct-way-to-statically-link-in-gfortran-libraries-on-osx)

Answer (score 2):

I think the meaning of the bold part is actually

> gfortran then **puts** the library code inside the
>   program created

That means using `-static` should be enough, there is no additional step. Just be advised you will need a static version of all the libraries that you link with.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old tracker, but maybe somebody will be still interested in the solution that works.

Let's say we have code:

```
! fort_sample.f90
program main
  write (*,*) 'Hello'
  stop
end
```

First, compile the stuff:

```
gfortran -c -o fort_sample.o fort_sample.f90
```

Then, link stuff

```
ld -o ./fort_sample -no_compact_unwind \
-arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 \
-lSystem \
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.a \
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.a \
/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/6.3.0/libgcc.a \
fort_sample.o
```

You can execute it

```
./fort_sample
 Hello
```

You can notice that quadmath is no longer there

```
> otool -L fort_sample
fort_sample:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.51.1)
```

I guess this is what you were looking for in a first place. No removing dylibs, no symbolic links, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the option is `-static-libgfortran`.  This means that the Fortran specific libraries of gfortran will be included into the executable. These are libraries are automatically found for a good installation of gfortran. This should produce an executable that should run on other computers with the same OS, even if that computer doesn't have gfortran installed.  This option likely doesn't statically link all libraries, so there is some risk that some other shared library used on your computer won't be available on the other computer.

Comment: True, I thought about mentioning that, but will that be enough? Isn't `-static-libgcc` (if I recall it correctly) necessary too? On linux it always worked strange for me and I stay away from these.

Comment: LIkely not enough.  And, for example, static-libgcc isn't possible on Mac OS X.

Comment: I tried adding in the Makefile `static-libgcc`
It compiles OK but when I try to run the .exe from Matlab in a computer (same OSX) but without gfortran installed, I get this error:

`dyld: Library not loaded /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.0.dylb
Referenced from: "mypath"
Reason: Imagen not found`
@M.S.B. Is that the risk you mentioned? Is libquadmath library not statically linked? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong in the Makefile?