# Is there a straightforward way to build a static load in gfortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am on a Mac powerbook with Gnu Fortran installed

gfortran -static-libgfortran -o prog.exe prog.f
still produces an executable that tries to link to dynamic library routines. I am happy to load and compile whatever static library I need and also try to point gfortran to it. (This issue seems to have been around for several years) Is there no easy solution. Simple steps?) (In the tries below I clearly don't know what I am doing.)

```
gfortran -static -o prog.exe prog.f          
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
```

libquadmath.a and libcrt0.0 come up missing

```
sudo dnf install libcrt0.o-static
sudo: dnf: command not found
g -static-libgfortran -lgfortran.a -lquadmath.a -o prog prog.f                                                         
ld: library not found for -lgfortran.a
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728442/3967096

Comment: I have not implemented the suggestions yet, however the following seems relevant as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590525/correct-way-to-statically-link-in-gfortran-libraries-on-osx